# Authenticate users from Active Directory with UserPrincipalName or Mail with FreeRADIUS

Tags: active-directory, freeradius, samba4

According to this documentation: http://deployingradius.com/documents/configuration/active_directory.html ; FreeRADIUS can authenticate Active Directory users using Samba's `ntlm_auth`, and in fact it works really well with the MSCHAPv2 protocol.

But using this method it's only possible to authenticate users with `sAMAccountName` from AD and we would like to authenticate users with it's `userPrincipalName` or email addresses.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Explaining better what I need. I need a way to parse the user login input. So if a user tries to login with an email address por example it will call a helper program to do a LDAP search and return the `sAMAccountName` to feed `ntlm_auth`. There's the FreeRADIUS preprocess module, but I don't know if I can use it for this purpose.

Comment: Post the `filter` attribute from the `ldap` section in your `radiusd.conf`, or maybe the entire ldap section actually

Comment: I'm not using `ldap`. Actually I was not aware that I can use `ldap` to authenticate within AD for MSCHAPv2 authentication. Can you point-me additional documentation?

Comment: Oh, just re-read the question. I'm pretty sure you can't do it with `ntlm_auth` as it doesn't seem to work with UPNs, but with ldap binds you can change the filter to search for users by userPrincipalName attributes

Comment: I can safely use the LDAP backend with AD? It will work for EAP/MSCHAPv2 for Wireless and Wired 802.1x Authentication? Thanks!

Comment: Well, don't use LDAP, use LDAP-over-SSL (tcp/636, tcp/3269 for GC).

Comment: Not really talking about the security scope, I'm afraid if it will work. RADIUS is very restrictive in supported authentication methods. According to this matrix only `ntlm_auth` is supported: http://deployingradius.com/documents/protocols/compatibility.html

Comment: It's not RADIUS which is restrictive, PAP will work with anything.

And no you can't use LDAP to authenticate MSCHAPv2 with AD.

Comment: Yep but I can use PAP to authenticate 802.1x clients?

Comment: Yes with EAP-TTLS PAP

Comment: Let-me change the question a little bit.